# Solution for rotation $d\vec{r}/dt = \vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$.

Tags: lie-groups, rotations, matrix-exponential

Let's consider an equation:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}.
\end{equation}

This equation  might  be expressed  via "angular velocity" matrix:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}\tag{1}
    \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}= \hat{\Omega} \vec{r},
\end{equation}
where  the "angular velocity" matrix is
\begin{equation}
\Omega = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0         & \omega_z  & -\omega_y \\
-\omega_z & 0         & \omega_x  \\
\omega_y  & -\omega_x & 0         \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Also let's introduce matrixes $\hat{\vec{S}}_{x,y,z}$ ($SO(3)$ generators):

\begin{multline}
\Omega = 
\omega_x 
\begin{pmatrix}
0  & 0  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 1 \\
0  & -1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
\omega_y 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0  & -1 \\
0 &  0  & 0  \\
1 &  0  & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
\omega_z 
\begin{pmatrix}
0  & 1  & 0 \\
-1 & 0  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
= \\ =
 i \omega_x 
\begin{pmatrix}
0  & 0  & 0  \\
0  & 0  & -i \\
0  & i & 0   \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
i \omega_y 
\begin{pmatrix}
0  &  0  & i  \\
0  &  0  & 0  \\
-i &  0  & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
i\omega_z 
\begin{pmatrix}
0  & -i & 0 \\
i  & 0  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.  
\end{multline}

\begin{multline}
\hat{\vec{S}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0  & 0  & 0  \\
0  & 0  & -i \\
0  & i & 0   \\
\end{pmatrix}
\vec{e}_x
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0  &  0  & i  \\
0  &  0  & 0  \\
-i &  0  & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\vec{e}_y
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0  & -i & 0 \\
i  & 0  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\vec{e}_z  = 
\hat{S}_x \vec{e}_x +
\hat{S}_y \vec{e}_y + 
\hat{S}_z \vec{e}_z
.
\end{multline}

So, we can write a formal solution of~\eqref{eq:3} as:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:solmatrix}\tag{2}
    \vec{r} = e^{i (\vec{\omega} t\cdot\vec{\hat{S}})} \vec{r}_0.
\end{equation}

Now, if I use some convinient axes, I can write \eqref{eq:solmatrix} as:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:solmatrix1}
    \vec{r} = e^{i (\omega t\cdot\hat{S}_{z'})} \vec{r}_0,
\end{equation}
and in explicit form (using Taylor series expansion of $e^M$) it looks like:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:so2}\tag{3}
    \vec{r}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t) &  0\\ \sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \vec{r}_0 = \hat{R}_{z'}(\omega t) \vec{v}_0 ,
\end{equation}
where $\hat{R}_{z'}(\omega t)$ is a rotation matrix about $z'$.

Now a question. How can I write the solution \eqref{eq:solmatrix} in explicit form (via rotation matrix like \eqref{eq:so2})? I tried, but there are powers of ($\sum_m i \omega_m \hat{S}_m)^n$ in Taylor series, which is not clear how to simplify. I can't see what they should collapse into.

Comment: What do you mean by a solution of $(2)$? $(2)$ is not a differential equation.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I clarified the quastion

Comment: You can expand the argument inside the exponent as a Taylor series, and hope to find a pattern when taking successive powers.

Comment: @William Barnes I tried, but there are powers of $(\sum_i \omega_i \hat{S}_i)^n$ in Taylor series, which is not clear how to simplify. I can't see what they should collapse into.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You say that you can convert (2) to (3), but you want a different way to do it?

Comment: @Calvin Khor Yes, I can convert (2) to (3), this is just recording a solution in a special coordinate system, where $\vec\omega = \omega_{z'}\hat{e}_{z'} $. I want record solution in arbitrary coordinates using Taylor expansion of $e^M$.

Comment: So you're asking for the change of variables?

Comment: @CalvinKhor No, I can apply transition to a new variables for (3) (but that's after using Taylor expansion of $e^M$) . I want do it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll focus my answer on computing the matrix exponential. Consider components of the unit vector $\hat{\omega}^a  = \omega^a /|\omega| $. Splitting the exponential into odd/ even terms

$$ E=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left( i |\omega|\hat{\omega}^a S^a \right)^n}{n!}   = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n |\omega|^{2n}(\hat{\omega}^aS^a)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+i \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n |\omega|^{2n+1}(\hat{\omega}^aS^a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$

The components $jk$ of the $\operatorname{so}(3)$ rotation generator $a$ are $S^{ajk}=i\epsilon^{ajk} $. Consider

$$\left[ (\hat{\omega}^aS^a)^2\right]^{jl}=\hat{\omega}^a \hat{\omega}^b S^{ajk}S^{bkl}=\delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j\hat{\omega}^l$$

The last equality follows$^\dagger $ by using the 'contracted epsilon identity' as well as the fact that $\hat{\omega}^a \hat{\omega}^a =1 $. We also note that RHS is a projection operator$^\ddagger$, hence

$$\left[ (\hat{\omega}^aS^a)^{2n}\right]^{jl}=\delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j\hat{\omega}^l$$

$$\left[ (\hat{\omega}^aS^a)^{2n+1}\right]^{jl}=\left[ \hat{\omega}^aS^a \right]^{jl}$$
Substitute back into the sums

$$ E^{jl}=\delta^{jl}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n |\omega|^{2n}}{(2n)!}(\delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j\hat{\omega}^l) +i \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n |\omega|^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\left[ \hat{\omega}^aS^a \right]^{jl} $$

$$E^{jl}=\delta^{jl}+(\delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j\hat{\omega}^l)\left(\cos(|\omega|)-1\right) +i\left[ \hat{\omega}^aS^a \right]^{jl}\sin(|\omega|)$$

$$E^{jl}=\hat{\omega}^j\hat{\omega}^l+(\delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j\hat{\omega}^l)\cos(|\omega|) +i\left[ \hat{\omega}^aS^a \right]^{jl}\sin(|\omega|)$$

Those are the components of the matrix. In matrix form it's probably not going to be very pretty, so I'll leave it there.

$\dagger$ Like this

$$ \hat{\omega}^a \hat{\omega}^b S^{ajk}S^{bkl}=i^2\hat{\omega}^a \hat{\omega}^b \epsilon^{ajk}\epsilon^{bkl}=\hat{\omega}^a \hat{\omega}^b \epsilon^{ajk}\epsilon^{blk}=\hat{\omega}^a \hat{\omega}^b \left( \delta^{ab}\delta^{jl}-\delta^{al}\delta^{bj} \right) \\= \hat{\omega}^a \hat{\omega}^a \delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j \hat{\omega}^l =  \delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j \hat{\omega}^l $$

$\ddagger$ By direct computation
$$  (\delta^{jl}-\hat{\omega}^j \hat{\omega}^l)(\delta^{lm}-\hat{\omega}^l \hat{\omega}^m)= \delta^{jl}\delta^{lm}+\hat{\omega}^j \hat{\omega}^l \hat{\omega}^l \hat{\omega}^m-\delta^{jl}\hat{\omega}^l \hat{\omega}^m-\delta^{lm}\hat{\omega}^j \hat{\omega}^l \\ =\delta^{jm}-\hat{\omega}^j \hat{\omega}^m$$

Comment: Thank you. I can't reproduce rotation matrix from E for the z-axis rotation case.

Comment: That would be because I neglected a $-1$ after the $\cos$; should be fixed now!

Comment: Thank you. Therefore, Rodrigues' formula was obtained from matrix exponential